# NullReferenceException in Https Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am getting NullReferenceException in my Https Middleware when running concurrent connections to my webApp while load testing. I am unable to reproduce this locally on kestral. The application in hosted in an Azure webapp.

Here is my middleware code. The exception is thrown on line 22: await next();

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace MyWebApp.Mvc.Extensions
{
    public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequireHttps(this IApplicationBuilder builder, bool isDeveloper = false)
        {
            if (builder == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
            }

            return builder.Use(
                async (context, next) =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.IsHttps || isDeveloper)
                    {
                        await next();
                        return;
                    }

                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Only secure HTTPS connections permitted.");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception from my logs

> [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:
>   An unhandled exception has occurred: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Items()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ActionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
>   context, ObjectResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
>   Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MyWebApp.Mvc.Extensions.ApplicationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\code\MyWebApp\src\MyWebApp.Mvc\Extensions\ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:line
>   22
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here or how to prevent this exception?

Comment: `next` is a delegate; you need to check for null: `await next?.Invoke();`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that helps prevent the exception. I'm still lost as to where the exception originates, it only occurs under load.